# PHP - PDO - MYSQL - Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm going mad about this error...

> =>  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

I'v executed this query in HeidiSql and it works... what I wrong??
Thank you before...

```
$sql = "select *
            from projects pr
            join projectTexts prt on pr.idProject = prt.idProject
            join images img on pr.idImage = img.idImage
            where ";
    if($idProject != '#')
        $sql .= "pr.idProject = :idp and ";
    if($status != '#') {
        $sql .= "pr.status = :sts and ";
    }
    $sql .= "prt.idLanguage = :idl
            order by pr.idProject desc
            limit :qt";
    $getProjectWithTexts = $db->prepare($sql);
    if($idProject != '#')
        $getProjectWithTexts->bindParam(':idp',$idProject);
    if($status != '#')
        $getProjectWithTexts->bindParam(':sts',$status);
    $getProjectWithTexts->bindParam(':idl',$idLanguage);
    $getProjectWithTexts->bindParam(':qt',$qt);
    $getProjectWithTexts->execute();
    return $getProjectWithTexts;
```

Comment: Why did you post only a stub of error message? Why did you omit the most helpful part?

Comment: Echo out your query (`$sql`), and check to make sure it looks good. Try running it in the command line or phpmyadmin with the correct bindings replaced. Does it work? Examine the full error message. Where does it say it's breaking down?

Comment: "select *
            from projects pr
            join projectTexts prt on pr.idProject = prt.idProject
            join images img on pr.idImage = img.idImage
            where"

'where' what?

Comment: @aynber I've written that in HeidiSQL it works...

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile it is concat with if statement. If these "if" don't proc, the sql query is continued however with -> prt.idLanguage = :idl
            order by pr.idProject desc
            limit :qt

Comment: I do not think that you executed the above code with if statements in heidisql. You executed a single sql statement, which is different. So, for debugging purposes, you need to consider the full error message and the final sql statement that was executed. Since we do not have these information, we cannot help you.

Comment: The echo print what I've executed in HeidiSQL. However I'v solved it.

Answer (score -1):

My question is right and the solution is that for bindParam with "limit" you have to set this:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);
```